# How to set BigQuery Proxy in PowerBI without admin privileges on windows machine

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, proxy, powerbi, gcloud

I am using Google Bigquery connector on PowerBI to connect to a GCP project, but bigquery APIs are only accessible if we use a proxy to enable private access. Is there a way to set proxy in Google Bigquery connector of PowerBI.

I can change the host file in machine(and it will work) and but it is not allowed as I am not admin. So looking for ways to set proxy in powerBI directly.
I tried the env variable(not sure if valid) but its not working -

```
# Override using an environment variable
CLOUDSDK_API_ENDPOINT_OVERRIDES_BIGQUERY=storage-vialink1.p.googleapis.com
```

GCloud also I cant install on the machine. What are the ways I can go ahead?
ref - https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/topic/endpoint-override